# Uppercase Aplhanumeric characters as SVG?

Tags: svg

Im working on a little person project inspired by http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298

I'd like to create individual svg elements that represent uppercase characters. If anyone could answer whether it is possible/how I could do this that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not clear. can you elaborate more?

Comment: Apologies @fawzan, 

for example is it possible to make an svg element for an 'A' character  in the form below:
http://www.decodeunicode.org/en/u+1d5d4/data/glyph/196x196/1D5D4.gif

I was hoping to take an alphanumeric user input and turn each letter into an svg element that I append to the DOM as part of a wider project.

Comment: Of Course, you can make anything with SVG

Comment: find/download/run an SVG editor, draw the characters you want in it.